# Is there a downside to using multiple nested for-loops in R for running intensive matrix calculations?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, lapply

In the example code presented below, I use 3 nested for-loops to expand a list of elements (from the `matList` list object) into a series of matrices, with example simple calculations between the below listed vectors and the code-generated/expanded matrices. This is done by executing function `createBucket()`. The code works as intended, with the output of running the function `createBucket(3)` shown in the image at the bottom.

This is a simple extraction from larger code. The calculations in the larger code are intensive with many matrices and vectors "speaking to each other" with the transfer of data between them. The larger code works with large datasets. I also understand that for-loops are not necessarily slower than `apply` functions.

Is there a downside to nesting multiple for-loops like this? There are more loops and nesting in the larger code this example derives from. I tried `lapply()` but the advantage of a for-loop is that it is easier to develop algorithms and troubleshoot by executing each line of code, line by line, to get it working right. It is easier to visualize and understand.

Also, secondarily, are there other more streamlined, yet comprehensible, ways to get at what I'm doing with `createBucket()`?

Code:

```
seriesVector <- function() {c("mat_One", "mat_Two")}
matList <- list(mat_One = c("Boy", "Cat"),mat_Two = c("Boy", "Bat"))
allocate <- list(mat_One = c(0.6,0.5,0.4),mat_Two = c(0.4,0.5,0.6))
flowVector <- c(6,5,4)

createBucket <- function(nbr_rows) {
  series <- seriesVector()
  flowMat <- vector("list", length = length(series))
  
  # sequences through each of the series listed in "seriesVector"
  for (i in seq_along(series)) {
    series_name <- series[i]
    mat_elements <- matList[[series_name]]
    mat_list <- vector("list", length = length(mat_elements))
    
    # sequences through each vector element (Boy/Cat/etc.) for each series listed in "matList"
    for (j in seq_along(mat_elements)) {
      element <- mat_elements[j]
      mat <- matrix(0, nbr_rows, 4)
      colnames(mat) <- c('Inflow','Due','Cover_due','Outflow')
      
      # sequences through each element of "allocate" and "flowVector" by the number of rows in
      # the matrices, and for each series and each element in the matrices calculates columns
      for (k in 1:nbr_rows) {
        allocate_value <- allocate[[series_name]][k]
        flow_value <- flowVector[k]
        mat[k, "Inflow"] <- allocate_value * flow_value
      }
      
      mat_list[[j]] <- mat
    }
    
    names(mat_list) <- mat_elements
    flowMat[[i]] <- setNames(mat_list, mat_elements)
  }
  
  names(flowMat) <- series
  return(flowMat)
}
createBucket(3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if its faster, but definitely more compact would be to map everything out rather than a bunch of loops. Here is a pseudo-one liner that recreates your function. I recommend trying this out and doing some speed tests for yourself.

```r
library(tidyverse)

seriesVector <- function() {c("mat_One", "mat_Two")}
matList <- list(mat_One = c("Boy", "Cat"),mat_Two = c("Boy", "Bat"))
allocate <- list(mat_One = c(0.6,0.5,0.4),mat_Two = c(0.4,0.5,0.6))
flowVector <- c(6,5,4)


createBucket <- function(){
map(allocate, \(alc) alc*flowVector) |>
  map2(matList, \(alc, matL) expand.grid(V1 = matL, 
                                         Inflow = alc,
                                         Due = 0,
                                         Cover_due = 0,
                                         Outflow = 0)) |>
  map(\(dfs) group_split(dfs, V1, .keep = FALSE) |>
        map(as.matrix))  |>
  map2(matList, ~set_names(.x, .y))
}

createBucket()
#> $mat_One
#> $mat_One$Boy
#>      Inflow Due Cover_due Outflow
#> [1,]    3.6   0         0       0
#> [2,]    2.5   0         0       0
#> [3,]    1.6   0         0       0
#> 
#> $mat_One$Cat
#>      Inflow Due Cover_due Outflow
#> [1,]    3.6   0         0       0
#> [2,]    2.5   0         0       0
#> [3,]    1.6   0         0       0
#> 
#> 
#> $mat_Two
#> $mat_Two$Boy
#>      Inflow Due Cover_due Outflow
#> [1,]    2.4   0         0       0
#> [2,]    2.5   0         0       0
#> [3,]    2.4   0         0       0
#> 
#> $mat_Two$Bat
#>      Inflow Due Cover_due Outflow
#> [1,]    2.4   0         0       0
#> [2,]    2.5   0         0       0
#> [3,]    2.4   0         0       0
```

Comment: Looks slick, my first time seeing `map()`. Will look on W3 Schools and see if they have lessons on this function. Will run some speed tests and report back.

Comment: Curious Jorge, when looking into `map` you might also have a look at its companion `reduce` (and their venerable base R anchestors `Map` and `Reduce`). The first one mutates, the second aggregates, and a sequence of both stringed together with the pipe operator can make life in R so much easier (think e.g. passing the result of `list.files` to your data importer of choice, selecting only a couple of variables and finally reducing all into one dataframe). See e.g. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#functionals

Comment: Yeah, I am a really big fan of `map` and `reduce`. Admittedly, I probably did a few "no-no"s  by mixing lambda style anonymous functions (i.e., `\(...)`) with the tidyverse anonymous function (i.e., `~`). Also, there is probably a way to optimize this so there are fewer number of `map` calls. Overall, I find that when I start needed a ton of loops, I probably need to rethink my approach, because there is usually a better way to do things through vectors. With that being said, if its not broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Interestingly, the for-loop version is clocking in faster than the map version. I'm going to build out both in parallel for a while and keep running speed tests.

Comment: You should look at this for mapping in parallel: https://furrr.futureverse.org/